# How to display status messages in admin panel

Tags: wp-admin, forms, admin-menu, settings-api

I recently followed the steps here https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API in order a create a setting page for my theme.
The code works, the data gets saved in the database without any status indicating it was saved.
Now lets say something happened and the form could not submit. 
How can I make WordPress in such a way that after submitting the form, It shows the status message whether the data was sent successfully or not without using ajax.

Comment: Have you tried using [`add_settings_error()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_error)? That function does exactly what you're after. If you did and it doesn't work, you need to provide the code you're currently using. Otherwise we can't really help you implement it.

Comment: thanks. I prefer to use another function `settings_errors();`. But all still gives the desired output

Comment: You need to use both… `settings_errors()` only displays the errors/messages added by `add_settings_error()`. They are intended to be used together.